# Instrumentation amplifier, discrete or integrated?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, circuit-design, instrumentation-amplifier, cost

Since integrated instrumentation amplifiers are so readily available, does it still make sense to incorporate an instrumentation amp discretely built from multiple opamps and resistors? Would one see discrete instrumentation amplifiers in professional designs?

Comment: Pick the best InAmp you can for a particular function and I'll find a three op-amp solution that outperforms it in some way.

Comment: The hardest part about discrete is matched resistors I think. Integrated does seem lacking but matched resistors are so expensive.

Comment: @Andyaka, but not without underperforming in some other way (for example, power, board area, or cost).

Comment: Horses for courses.

Comment: only time I have knocked together an InstruAmp out of discrete OPAMPS in the last 10years was due to an artificial constraint from the program "you shall only use TLO8* OPAMPS". Not worth it otherwise

Comment: I actually needed very good gain-bandwidth ( circa 100 MHz) and very low DC offset. It was about ten years ago but it had to be done.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that attempting to go discreet to save on cost would be misguided, but going discreet to achieve niche performance targets is necessary but comes with a price tag?

Comment: I think generalizing an answer is a mistake for this site.

Comment: @Andyaka -- I'm sure you can, but not for a reasonable amount of time or effort.  It's been a long time since I've had to twiddle a pot to optimize CMRR

Comment: @Andyaka, for your special need, it might have made more sense to go with a modest gain inamp for CMRR, and then a high gain single ended stage, though I haven't looked for high-frequency inamps.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Depends what is implied by high-frequency in the context. The AD8429 InAmp is specified for 1.2MHz at 100 gain. It's not even that exotic a part :-)

Comment: It was ten years ago so probably what was around then wasn't as good as now. Gain required was 1000 and bandwidth (flat) was 50 kHz.

Comment: I also remember that I had to choose front end opamps with circa 1.1 nV / root hertz noise. Maybe that was the big deal and not dc accuracy. It was years ago. I think they were linear tech opamps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes just about zero sense to build an Instrumentation Amp from discrete components if you really need the CMRR of an instrumentation amp.

Because of resistor mismatch and temperature drift, there is almost no chance that you can match the CMRR performance.

Comment: 3 quid gets you a resistor tolerance of 0.01 % and a tempco of 2 ppm per degC. How does that compare with the internalised resistors?

Comment: @Andyaka -- yes, but you still need enough knowledge and skill to place the resistors on a board in such a way that they are equally impacted by temperature.  I'll leave that as an exercise best practiced by the people who do this on the silicon.  3 quid also buys a pretty good inamp these days!  I'll back off a bit and say that if you can find an inamp that does what you need, buy it.  I also think that if you can't find an inamp that does what you need, you should be looking at your approach.